# Adding the ArrayList<StudentBean> values to HashMap<Integer, StudentBean>

Tags: java, arraylist, java-8, hashmap

I have a List:

`List<StudentBean> resultList`

StudentBean has something like with getters and setters:

`{ Integer StudentId, String StudentName, String Section}`.

I have a map with values: `Map<Integer, StudentBean> orginialStudentDetails`

Now I want to add/replace the values from resultList to orginialStudentDetails, how can I achieve that?

Tried:

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, StudentBean> entry : resultList .size()){
     orginialStudentDetails.put(entry.getKey(), resultList );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Joxtacy's [correct approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74527935/10584605):

```java
resultList.forEach(s -> originalStudentDetails.put(s.getStudentId(), s));
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what the class `StudentBean` look like, but something like the following might work.

```java
for (StudentBean studentBean : resultList) {
    originalStudentDetails.put(studentBean.getStudentId(), studentBean);
}
```

This is assuming that `StudentBean` has a method called `getStudentId` that returns an `int` or `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Java 8, by lambda:

```
Map<Integer, StudentBean> map = resultList.stream().filter(t -> t != null || t.getStudentId() != null).collect(Collectors.toMap(StudentBean::getStudentId, t -> t));
```

StudentId must not be repeat or null, or there will be a duplicate key exception.